# Flexible Constraints of View position when view is loaded

Tags: swift3, constraints, viewdidload

I'm new in  programming

I have 2 subviews in my main `RootView` (Magenta) - which are `AppView` (Orange) and `MenuBarView` (Black) -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLQnJ.jpg

I want the menubar to be in a certain position even when it is rotated so I've done something like this:

> Swift 3

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var MenuBarPosition = "Left"

func RefreshConstraints() {

    switch  MenuBarPosition {
    case "Right":
        self.ApplyMenuBarRight()
        (...)
    default:
        print("MenuBarPositionError")
    }


func ApplyMenuBarRight() {
    RootView.removeConstraints(ApplyMenuBarOnRightRemoveConstraints)  // This is an array
    RootView.addConstraints(ApplyMenuBarOnRightConstraints)           // Also an Array
    }
    (...)
}
```

When the screen is rotated, I've put

> Swift 3

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    RefreshConstraints()
}
```

to apply the changes. This works fine. Therefore I know my constraints and code for applying them are correct. However when I've tried to do:

> Swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    RootView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    MenuBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    AppView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    super.viewDidLoad()

    RefreshConstraints()

}
```

the subview constraints are not applied when the app is initially loaded and shows a magenta screen (i.e. `rootView` ) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyAc.jpg

What have I missed - for it not working correctly when the app is launched? Any help is appreciated, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer myself through more research and trial and error!

Rather than going for

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    RefreshConstraints()

    }
```

I moved the code under `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and it worked!

Hope this helps!